# Woocommerce Mystile Child Theme Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've created child themes before without issue however when I create one using Woocommerce Mystile theme it does not display properly with menu items missing and images resizing to be too large.
I made the child theme by creating a new folder in the wp-content>themes folder called mystile-child and creating style.css with the contents

```
/*
    Theme Name: Mystile Child
    Description: Mystile Child Theme
    Template: mystile
    */
```

I then created a functions.php file with the contents

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}
?>
```

this is what the parent theme looks like:
[image: Mystile Parent Theme]

This what the child theme looks like
[image: Mystile Child Theme]

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiousity - were the logo and other missing elements set up intially using the theme customizer (reached via the wordpress admin menu Appearance > Customize)?

If that's the case, then those settings are created outside of your theme and need to be reset or imported for your child theme. There are a few ways to accomplish this, the easiest way being with a plugin which imports/exports those Customizer settings.

Hope that helps,
Laura

Comment: No I had no logo to begin with. If you look at the first image of the parent theme what you see is the default layout for the Mystile theme. I don't understand how creating a child theme could mess with the top menu where the shopping cart etc should be. Have I missed something when setting up the child theme?

Comment: Hi there - can you link the site in question? It's difficult to troubleshoot this with screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed the problem following the advice found on Wordpress.org support forum here https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mystile-theme-child-header-problem

Seems more of temporary fix though and something that the people at Woocommerce should investigate.